# Adding texture uv map using scripting

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I am trying to add texture to my head object ( I used Flame model to create it) but the output doesn't have the uv map texture. Did I do something incorrect in adding texture?

````
def export_obj(): 
    # Open the CSV file to write the coordinates
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder_coor, "object_coordinates.csv")
    with open(output_path, "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write("Number,Object,LocationX,LocationY,LocationZ\n")

      
        for i in range(0, 11):

            bpy.ops.object.flame_random_shapes()

         
            bpy.ops.object.flame_random_expressions()

            # Set the current object
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)

            # Loop through the objects and write their coordinates to the file for this iteration
            for obj_name in ["FLAME2020-male", "Camera", "Light"]:
                obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]
                location = obj.location
                output_file.write("{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(i, obj_name, location.x, location.y, location.z))

            # Set the output .obj file path
            output_path_obj = os.path.join(output_folder_obj,"model{}.obj".format(i))

            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
            
            # Set the export settings
            bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=output_path_obj,
                                      use_selection=True,
                                      use_smooth_groups=True,
                                      use_smooth_groups_bitflags=True,
                                      use_normals=True,
                                      use_triangles=True,
                                      use_materials=False,
                                      keep_vertex_order=True)

            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            filename = "model{}.obj".format(i)
            with open(os.path.join(output_folder_obj, filename), "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            # Filter the lines to remove those starting with "vn" and "f"
            filtered_lines = [line for line in lines if not (line.startswith("vn") or line.startswith("f"))]
            # Read the contents of the original .obj file
            with open(original_obj_file, "r") as f:
                original_lines = f.readlines()
            # Filter the original lines to keep only those starting with "vt" and "f"
            original_filtered_lines = [line for line in original_lines if line.startswith("vt") or line.startswith("f")]
            # Combine the filtered lines from the output file and the original file
            combined_lines = filtered_lines + original_filtered_lines
            # Write the combined lines back to the output file
            with open(os.path.join(output_folder_obj, filename), "w") as f:
                f.writelines(combined_lines)
            
            uv_map_path = "/Users/tuanthanhnguyen/shared_docker/data/template.png"

            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="UVMap")
            
            mat.use_nodes = True

            # Add a Principled BSDF node to the material
            bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
            #bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]

            # Add an image texture node to the material
            tex = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
            tex.image = bpy.data.images.load(uv_map_path)

            # Connect the texture node to the BSDF node using the UV map
            uvmap = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')
            uvmap.uv_map = "Template"
            mat.node_tree.links.new(tex.outputs['Color'], bsdf.inputs['Base Color'])
            mat.node_tree.links.new(uvmap.outputs['UV'], tex.inputs['Vector'])

            # Create a new material output node and link it to the BSDF node
            out = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
            mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.outputs['BSDF'], out.inputs['Surface'])

            # Assign the material to the active object
            bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(mat)
               
            # Render the image
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
            # Set the output image file path
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder_img, "image{}.png".format(i))
            # Save the image
            bpy.data.images["Render Result"].save_render(filepath=output_path)
```
````

Comment: From a quick reading, it looks like your script exports a model (why?) and then makes a material with an image texture node plugged into a Principled BSDF node.

Comment: @L0Lock I'm preparing a dataset which contains 3D human head models. That's why I exported them and then added the texture.